# Getting error (TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int') while trying to plot pie

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have dataframe with the following properties:

```
 train_df.head()

    id  sentence    discourse_type
0   345C6337479E    [summer, one, greatest, times, high, school, s...   [Lead]
1   345C6337479E    [chance, take, break, school, sit, back, relax...   [Lead]
2   345C6337479E    [opinion, student, designed]    [Position]
3   345C6337479E    [thought, warm, sun, cool, water, late, nights...   [Evidence]
4   345C6337479E    [idea, summer, gives, everyone, light, happy, ...   [Evidence]


train_df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 107085 entries, 0 to 107084
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column          Non-Null Count   Dtype 
---  ------          --------------   ----- 
 0   id              107085 non-null  object
 1   sentence        107085 non-null  object
 2   discourse_type  107085 non-null  object
dtypes: object(3)
memory usage: 2.5+ MB
```

I'm trying to use pie plot on `discourse_type` column:

```
train_df['discourse_type'].plot.pie(figsize=(5, 5))
```

and I'm getting error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_22116/2957075597.py in <module>
----> 1 train_df['discourse_type'].plot.pie(figsize=(5, 5))

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in pie(self, **kwargs)
   1549         ):
   1550             raise ValueError("pie requires either y column or 'subplots=True'")
-> 1551         return self(kind="pie", **kwargs)
   1552 
   1553     def scatter(self, x, y, s=None, c=None, **kwargs):

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    970                     data.columns = label_name
    971 
--> 972         return plot_backend.plot(data, kind=kind, **kwargs)
    973 
    974     __call__.__doc__ = __doc__

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/__init__.py in plot(data, kind, **kwargs)
     68                 ax = plt.gca()
     69             kwargs["ax"] = getattr(ax, "left_ax", ax)
---> 70     plot_obj = PLOT_CLASSES[kind](data, **kwargs)
     71     plot_obj.generate()
     72     plot_obj.draw()

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py in __init__(self, data, kind, **kwargs)
   1572     def __init__(self, data, kind=None, **kwargs):
   1573         data = data.fillna(value=0)
-> 1574         if (data < 0).any().any():
   1575             raise ValueError(f"{self._kind} plot doesn't allow negative values")
   1576         MPLPlot.__init__(self, data, kind=kind, **kwargs)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/common.py in new_method(self, other)
     67         other = item_from_zerodim(other)
     68 
---> 69         return method(self, other)
     70 
     71     return new_method

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/arraylike.py in __lt__(self, other)
     38     @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__lt__")
     39     def __lt__(self, other):
---> 40         return self._cmp_method(other, operator.lt)
     41 
     42     @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__le__")

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in _cmp_method(self, other, op)
   5500 
   5501         with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
-> 5502             res_values = ops.comparison_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)
   5503 
   5504         return self._construct_result(res_values, name=res_name)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py in comparison_op(left, right, op)
    282 
    283     elif is_object_dtype(lvalues.dtype) or isinstance(rvalues, str):
--> 284         res_values = comp_method_OBJECT_ARRAY(op, lvalues, rvalues)
    285 
    286     else:

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py in comp_method_OBJECT_ARRAY(op, x, y)
     71         result = libops.vec_compare(x.ravel(), y.ravel(), op)
     72     else:
---> 73         result = libops.scalar_compare(x.ravel(), y, op)
     74     return result.reshape(x.shape)
     75 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/_libs/ops.pyx in pandas._libs.ops.scalar_compare()

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

How can I use pie plot on `discourse_type` column ?

Comment: Please provide a sample of the data as DataFrame constructor

Comment: Is your `discourse_type` data in the form of strings as opposed to lists of strings?

Comment: it's a string (the string pattern similar to list with one string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pie chart doesn't count occurencies of each group, it only plots a proportional representation of the numerical data in a column.

You have to do it yourself.
You can use groupby and then plot it. For example:

```
train_df.groupby("discourse_type")['discourse_type'].count()/
    .plot.pie(figsize=(5, 5))
```

EDIT:
`value_counts()` is even better (to keep the code clean):

```
test['discourse_type'].value_counts().plot.pie(figsize=(5, 5))
```

[image]

Comment: and what if you want to add percentage here?